# First attempt to paste from a register requires pause after <C-R>

Tags: register

When I yank text into any register, the first attempt to paste the content in insert mode using <C-R> doesn't do anything if I follow it too quickly with the name of the register.  It works fine if I pause for a fraction of a second.  This need to wait only afflicts the first attempt to paste text after yanking it.

I haven't been able to find anything in the help or Google about whether this is deliberately designed in or whether it can be avoided.  Thanks for any pointers to documentation on this, if it is deliberate.

Comment: Are you typing <C-r><register-name> or just <C-r>?

Comment: I am following <C-r> with the name of the register too quickly.  It fails on the first attempt at pasting, but works find on subsequent attempts.  The first attempt works is fine if I pause a fraction of a second after <C-r>.  Thanks for pointing out this missing detail.  I've added it to the question.

Comment: Does it happen with `vim -Nu NONE`?

Comment: Does `:map <C-r>` output anything? Could be there's a mapping which needs to time out.

Comment: @Maxim Kim: I'm noticing now how inconsistent the problem is. It's not manifesting itself right now, even with the Vim session that I've been using for days. I will try to note what circumstances cause this behaviour to arise.  I was really hoping that it was a known effect.

Comment: @Friedrich: `:map <C-r>` outputs `No mapping found`

Comment: Good, now we know it's not a mapping that's causing this.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think I'd map something to a majorly used key.  But I've done dumb things before, so it was worth a look.

Comment: I wouldn't have thought you had. People put all sorts of "clever ideas" into plugins. Try a couple of plugins and you might end up with a broken config.